# Adding home page components from salesforce classic to lightning pages

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, home-page-component, app-builder

Is there a way to add the custom / standard salesforce home page components from the salesforce classic to lightning pages. I am not able to see the components listed for home page under lightning pages app builder.

Then after going through certain links i understand that it cannot be done. I would like to know whether there are any lightning tags/commands which can be used directly to pull the home page components into lightning components.

Here is a sample of home page custom components which i would like to bring into lightning app builder/Page.

[image: Home page Component in classic]

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that!

They are totally different technologies - although they have the name `components`, they are different and only a manual creation of a lightning component to be like the classic home page component would give you what you want

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any direct way to pull these custom links on the home page components into my Apex code ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct one to one mapping. Some home page component have Lightning equivalents, but not all.

The ones you show in the screenshot looks like a list of links? You could either create your own custom Lightning Components and expose it to Lightning Pages or perhaps use the existing Rich Text component?

Comment: Thank you for the update. Is there any direct way to pull these custom links on the home page components into my Apex code ?

Comment: I'm not to familiar, but I would take a look at the HomePageCompnent https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_homepagecomponent.htm